# How to get first number from file name, find folder matching the number and move file to folder?

Tags: batch-file

I've been trying to do the following.

Lets say I have 3 files in a folder named `Documents`:

```
123 Car.pdf
456 Dog.pdf
987 Lion.pdf
```

I want to create a batch file (.bat) that

- read the file names in the folder "documents" but only till the space
  (read: 123, 456, 987)
- then search the drive for folders matching with the searched file
  name (123, 456, 987)
- and if a folder that is named with `123`, `456`, `987` is found then move
  the file `123 Car.pdf` to folder `123`, file `456 Dog.pdf` to folder
  `456`, `987 Lion.pdf` to folder `987` and so on.

Comment: What i tried was a complete failure and incomplete regarding the task at hand : "find "path \TEST AREA\" -name %%i "123*" 
{move %%i "path \TEST AREA\123\" {} +}". Tried this but its incomplete: for /r %%x in (123*.*) do move "%%x" "path TEST AREA\123"
;  Also tried other alternatives but i couldn't make it work so i deleted them. And yes, i am a "noob".

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it take the first part of the filename and move the file to a folder named the same but i can not make it search for such a folder and then move the file in it. it just creates it by itself and moves it.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=C:\Desktop\TEST AREA\"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1*" %%a IN (
    'dir /b /a-d "* * *.txt"'
) DO (
    MD %%a
    MOVE "%%a %%b" "C:\Desktop\TEST AREA\%%a\"
)
PAUSE
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

I need it to search for the folder and move it there, not creat it and move it.

Comment: if you try to create a folder that already exists, you just get an error message, which you can redirect to `NUL`: `md %%a 2>nul`. This doesn't hurt your already existing folder.

Comment: …or to `IF NOT EXIST %%a\ MD %%a`

Comment: I previously tried if not exist but i did not make it work. Probably did something wrong. Your line worked :) Thank you

Comment: Another issue is it is not looking into subfolder to check if the folder exists ... ?